# Customize Panorama List in Windows Phone 8 Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

### Customize Panorama List in Windows Phone 8 Xaml

I am developing windows phone 8 book reader application. I am using panorama list to load pages. Because of its default style panorama shows part of another page in the same view.I need to show single page in single view and it should fit.Any help?

Comment: sure, listbox behaviour is not same as panorama control

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible in panorama control but you can use horizontal list

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <tolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                <tolkit:GestureListener Flick="GestureListener_Flick"></tolkit:GestureListener>
            </tolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <ListBox Name="lstMyList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectionChanged="lstlstMyList_SelectionChanged_1">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image Height="480" Width="500" Margin="-25,30,0,0" Source="{Binding Image}"/>
                            <TextBlock  Name="txbMainHeading" Text="{Binding Message}" Margin="80,10,0,0" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Medium" Foreground="#cc6600"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="60,0,0,0" FontSize="18" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="350"></TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: How to add flip effect to listbox?

Answer (score 0):

You can Pivot control. It shows one view on one page.